# Error when using data from request.post directly in google places nearby_search

Tags: django, google-places-api, google-geocoder

This is my views.py

```
def map(request):
ngos_addr = []
loc = ""
if request.method == 'POST':
    loc = request.POST.get('location', '')
#In this I want to send the location loc to the api
query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
        location=loc, keyword='ngos and non profit organizations',
        radius=20000)
for place in query_result.places:
    place.get_details()
    #Create list having all nearby ngos addresses
    ngos_addr.append (place.formatted_address)
return render_to_response('display_map.html', {'location': ngos_addr}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is my display_map.html in templates

```
<body>
    {% if location  == '' %}
        <h2>Enter your location</h2>
        <form action="/map" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
            <input type='input' value="" name='location'/>
        </form>
    {% else %}
        {% load easy_maps_tags %}
        <!--Some for to iterate over list and show the map?-->
        <!-- Default map with 600x600 dimensions -->
        <!-- I also tried this to simply show a map for a single location 
        which the user eneterd using loc variable, but it didn't work-->
        {% easy_map location  600 600  using "easy_maps/map.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

I'm want to pass the loc to this, so that it shows map for the loc given by the user.

It works if I enter a location in

```
query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
    location="Delhi, India", keyword='ngos and non profit      
    organizations',radius=20000)
```

but not if I get it from the request.POST.get, and assign the variable to location in above code.

But when I use loc (a varible) to assign things to that, it gives me [this](http://gyazo.com/fbf7234f9848febe1c48b0b863a36e47) error. I checked the type(loc) and even tried changing it to str, but it still does not pass that value and the error pops up.

Why is this error coming, what is wrong in this?

I also want to show multiple markers returned by ngos_addr list (which has the address of nearby ngos) in the same map, is there any way in Django easy maps to do this? or is their any other options to do this?

I'm using Python 2.7.3, Django 1.6.2, [Python Google Places](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places) wrapper for Google Places API.

Comment: If you print the `loc` variable after it has been assigned, what is it's value?

Comment: I printed it, it's fine and has whatever I give. The type was unicode, I also made it str but still it didn't worked.

Comment: [this](http://gyazo.com/fbf7234f9848febe1c48b0b863a36e47) error tells the lat and lan should be the key value pair. Please check the type of that and try to change. If the type is in dict, then check the value what you are getting in the variable loc.